# Can't install Ubuntu 12.10 from USB

Tags: installation, usb, authentication

I can't install Ubuntu 12.10 from USB drive. I tried LiLi, UNetBootin, Universal usb installer and others for create USB. It boots and I can select "Try Ubuntu without installing" and "Install Ubuntu on hard disk". But when I select any option, Ubuntu screen with 5 dots shows, it fills all 5 dots with red color and after it shows console with "Authentication failure" maybe 5 times in a row. And it hangs there. Can you help me how can I get it working please?

My notebook is Lenovo G580. I tried disable/enable UEFI boot but it doesn't help. I don't have DVD drive so I can't install it from CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the copy of Ubuntu you put on your usb drive has an error. Verify the .iso file you used to create the live usb following [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

If that isn't the problem, make the live usb again. If it still doesn't work, try a new usb drive.

Comment: MD5SUM is alright. I can install it in VirtualBox from this .iso. Tried 3 USB keys and none is working. :(

Comment: Do you have a way of taking a photo of the error messages exactly as they are? Also, you can try installing 12.04 LTS and see if that works.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 11.10 and it boots! But when I click on Install icon on desktop it does nothing. But when I click on Firefox or other icon it starts that program. I am really upset and I'll lend CD/DVD  drive from my friend and I'll install it from DVD. 

Thank you for your help.

BTW Windows bootable USB works and I can even install it without problems. It is weird.